# What does the # symbol mean in this bash for loop?

Tags: bash

Just a simple question here.

I don't understand what the "#" means in the following for loop:

```
my_S1_array=(*S1.txt)
my_S2_array=(*S2.txt)

for ((i=0; i<${#my_S1_array[@]}; i++));
do
    echo "Running stats for ${my_S1_array[$i]} and ${my_S2_array[$i]}"
done
```

Is the "${#my_S1_array[@]}" at the start of the for loop the same thing as "$my_S1_array[@]" (i.e. just omitting the hashtag). Not sure what the hashtag does here.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try reading the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)? Look for the section on `${#parameter}`

Comment: Nope! Never came across this particular manual - all of what I learned was from cheat sheets and module tutorials at school. thanks!